# C# DateTime.Ticks equivalent in Java

Tags: c#, java

What is the Java equivalent of DateTime.Ticks in C#?

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2010, 9, 14, 0, 0, 0);
Console.WriteLine("Ticks: {0}", dt.Ticks);
```

What will be the equivalent of above mentioned code in Java?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Well, java.util.Date/Calendar only have precision down to the millisecond:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();    
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0); // Clear the millis part. Silly API.
calendar.set(2010, 8, 14, 0, 0, 0); // Note that months are 0-based
Date date = calendar.getTime();
long millis = date.getTime(); // Millis since Unix epoch
```

That's the nearest effective equivalent. If you need to convert between a .NET ticks value and a `Date`/`Calendar` you basically need to perform scaling (ticks to millis) and offsetting (1st Jan 1AD to 1st Jan 1970).

Java's built-in date and time APIs are fairly unpleasant. I'd personally recommend that you use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead. If you could say what you're really trying to do, we can help more.

EDIT: Okay, here's some sample code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    private static final long TICKS_AT_EPOCH = 621355968000000000L;
    private static final long TICKS_PER_MILLISECOND = 10000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long ticks = 634200192000000000L;

        Date date = new Date((ticks - TICKS_AT_EPOCH) / TICKS_PER_MILLISECOND);
        System.out.println(date);

        TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(utc);
        calendar.setTime(date);
        System.out.println(calendar);
    }
}
```

Note that this constructs a Date/Calendar representing the *UTC* instant of 2019/9/14. The .NET representation is somewhat fuzzy - you can create two DateTime values which are the same except for their "kind" (but therefore represent different instants) and they'll claim to be equal. It's a bit of a mess :(

Comment: In my current scenario i had saved Ticks value calculated in C#; now what i want is read that tick value and get the same date in Java.

Comment: @Asoo: Okay. Walking to work ATM - code in twenty minutes. Basically divide by ticks per millisecond and subtract an offset. You should also bear timezone offsets in mind.

Comment: Thanks @Skeet....But if i want to calculate the ticks in Java and read them in C#.....i tried this but it does not gives the identical value: TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(utc);
        calendar.set(2010,8,14,0,0,0);

        System.out.println(calendar.getTimeInMillis() * TICKS_PER_MILLISECOND + TICKS_AT_EPOCH);

Comment: @Asoo: It looks like it's keeping the existing millis-in-second value - call `calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);` before the other call to `calendar.set()`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: There's a tiny, tiny, tiny improvement you could make, if you added 5000 to (ticks - TICKS_AT_EPOCH) before you divide by TICKS_PER_MILLISECOND. Then you'd be rounding to the nearest millisecond instead of truncating down.

Comment: @RenniePet: I wouldn't say that's always an improvement - it depends on the situation. But in the OP's case, it looks like there'll never be a sub-millisecond value anyway.

Answer (score 23):

In Java is:

```
long TICKS_AT_EPOCH = 621355968000000000L; 
long tick = System.currentTimeMillis()*10000 + TICKS_AT_EPOCH;
```

Comment: using Local zone (analogue of DateTime.Now.Ticks) `long tick = (System.currentTimeMillis() + TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset()) * 10000 + TICKS_AT_EPOCH;`

Comment: @Alex78191 has pointed out a good (missing) point as in answer. Time Zone must be considered otherwise will not calculate correct current time outside of GMT. "import java.util.*" is required to compile suggested change.

Answer (score 10):

System.nanoTime() gives you nanoseconds in Java (since 1.6). You'll still need to shift/rescale, but no precision will be lost.

Comment: nanoTime has nothing with clock time, which means it can't be converted or compared with Ticks from .net DateTime. Here is quote from javadoc: This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time. The value returned represents nanoseconds since some fixed but arbitrary time (perhaps in the future, so values may be negative).

Answer (score 3):

Base on Jon Skeet I developed this class

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateHelper {

    private static final long TICKS_AT_EPOCH = 621355968000000000L;
    private static final long TICKS_PER_MILLISECOND = 10000;

    public static long getUTCTicks(Date date){

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);

        return (calendar.getTimeInMillis() * TICKS_PER_MILLISECOND) + TICKS_AT_EPOCH;

    }

    public static Date getDate(long UTCTicks){

        return new Date((UTCTicks - TICKS_AT_EPOCH) / TICKS_PER_MILLISECOND);

    }

}
```

It works for me

Comment: this is the only one that worked for me? maybe i was missing something!

Comment: +1 It works, although the method names have totally nothing to do with UTC. Just `Ticks from Date` and `Date from Ticks`. This is useful for an Android app written in Xamarin, the DB libraries store DateTime as ticks in the DB - this works for it.

Answer (score 0):

There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond, and C# considers the beginning of time January 1, 0001 at midnight. Here's a one-liner which converts an Instant to ticks.

```java
public static long toTicks(Instant i)
{
   return Duration.between(Instant.parse("0001-01-01T00:00:00.00Z"), i).toMillis() * 10000;
}
```

Comment: A tick is a 100 nanoseconds.

Comment: Whoops! Fixed the answer. Thanks for the callout. I think the code snippet was correct. Does it seem fine to you?

Answer (score 0):

And for those of us showing up trying to get the current number of *ticks* as defined by the UUID specification:

```
/**
    Returns the current tick count.
    Ticks are the number of 100 ns intervals since October 15, 1582
    @return
*/
private static long getUtcNowTicks() {

    final long UNIX_EPOCH_TICKS = 122192928000000000L; //Number of ticks from 10/16/1582 to 1/1/1970
    Instant i = Clock.systemUTC().instant(); //get the current time
    long ticks = UNIX_EPOCH_TICKS; // number of ticks as of 1/1/1970
    ticks += i.getEpochSecond()*10000000; //number of whole seconds (converted to ticks) since 1/1/1970
    ticks += i.getNano() / 100; //number of ticks since the start of the second

    return ticks;

    /*
    Some interesting tick values

    Date            Ticks
    ==========  ==================
    10/15/1582                   0  Start of UUID epoch; the date we switched to the Gregorian calendar)
     1/01/1601    5748192000000000  Start of Windows epoch (start of 1st Gregorian 400-year cycle)
    12/30/1899  100101312000000000  Start of Lotus 123, Excel, VB, COM, Delphi epoch
     1/01/1900  100103040000000000  Start of SQL Server epoch
     1/01/1970  122192928000000000  Start of UNIX epoch
     1/01/2000  131659776000000000
     1/01/2010  134815968000000000
     1/01/2020  137971296000000000
     1/19/2038  143714420469999999  UNIX Y2k38 problem (January 19, 2038  3:14:07 am)
    */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To convert .Net Ticks to millis in java use this :

```
static final long TICKS_PER_MILLISECOND = 10000;
long ticks = 450000000000L; // sample tick value
long millis = (ticks  / TICKS_PER_MILLISECOND);
```

Comment: Different epoch in C#/Java - see Pablo's answer