# convert date to c# ticks in java

Tags: java, .net, date, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# DateTime.Ticks equivalent in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706306/c-datetime-ticks-equivalent-in-java)

hello guys

can anybody tell me how to convert date to .Net ticks in java.
any help will be appreciative.

thanks

Comment: I'd say many Java do not know what .net ticks means. In case you do, you should explain.

Comment: looks like Jon Skeet's answer solves the problem!

Comment: @jarnbjo its giving the solution of converting ticks to date. I need to convert a date time into ticks.

Comment: @saijjo: So reversing the calculation in the response from `(ticks - TICKS_AT_EPOCH) / TICKS_PER_MILLISECOND` to `TICKS_AT_EPOCH + javaTime *  TICKS_PER_MILLISECOND` was an unreasonable task for you? Alternatively, you could have read the comments to Jon's response to find out that someone had done that job for you already.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

ticks = 621355968000000000L+javaMillis*10000;

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to check the icu4j library from the [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) project especially the [UniversalTimeScale](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/util/UniversalTimeScale.html) class which is similar to .Net ticks.

Comment: … specifically, the DOTNET_DATE_TIME selector there can be used to convert ticks into many other formats.

Answer (score 0):

> **DateTime.Ticks Property** The value of this property is the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00 A.M., January 1, 0001.
>
> *Date.getTime()* Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this Date object.

Accounting for the 1970 years offset and multiplying by ten seems to be the solution.