# What is the equivalent of DateTime.FromOADate() in Java (double to Datetime in Java)

Tags: c#, java, .net, datetime

*C#* has a `DateTime.FromOADate()` method.

What is the equivalent of `DateTime.FromOADate()` in *Java* ?

This is my C# code :

```
var b = new byte[8];
b[0] = 0x20;
b[1] = 0x64;
b[2] = 0xa8;
b[3] = 0xac;
b[4] = 0xb6;
b[5] = 0x65;
b[6] = 0xe4;
b[7] = 0x40;
var dbl = BitConverter.ToDouble(b, 0);
var dt = DateTime.FromOADate(dbl);
```

This is the output :

> 2014-05-14T17:00:21

How can i convert this byte array to java?

Comment: is your epoch time in binary ?

Comment: @seckin - I don't know C#.  But if you'd like to tell me what this function does, I'll be able to tell you whether it exists in Java.

Comment: Tell us: *What **exactly** is the format of the binary data you have?* Don't assume that `DateTime.FromBinary()` does what you need it to. Probably an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Why would you do such a thing?

Comment: But *where* are those 8 bytes *actually* coming from? This question makes no sense if they're just hard-coded into your application. *What are you trying to accomplish?*

Comment: It comes from in a socket application. is it important?

Comment: @seckin Yes. Is it coming from a .NET application, where someone is sending the result of `DateTime.ToBinary()` over a socket, then **that** is the problem; Whomever wrote the protocol made a stupid choice. Is this the case, and are you able to modify the source of the data?

Comment: @seckin - link to sources if you wish, but please don't paste that big block of code verbatim in your question.  I rolled it back.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you realize that your binary data is the binary represantation of an [OLE Automation date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) value?

So instead of getting `long`, you should get a `double` value from your array.

```
var b = new byte[8];
b[0] = 0x20;
b[1] = 0x64;
b[2] = 0xa8;
b[3] = 0xac;
b[4] = 0xb6;
b[5] = 0x65;
b[6] = 0xe4;
b[7] = 0x40;
var dbl = BitConverter.ToDouble(b, 0);
var dt = DateTime.FromOADate(dbl);
Console.WriteLine("{0:s}", dt);
```

Result is :

```
2014-05-14T17:00:21
```

I think the valid question should be: *What is the equivalent of DateTime.FromOADate() in Java ?*

Answer is:

```
public static Date fromDoubleToDateTime(double OADate) 
{
    long num = (long) ((OADate * 86400000.0) + ((OADate >= 0.0) ? 0.5 : -0.5));
    if (num < 0L) {
        num -= (num % 0x5265c00L) * 2L;
    }
    num += 0x3680b5e1fc00L;
    num -=  62135596800000L;

    return new Date(num);
}
```

Comment: This is good, but it assumes the OADate was based on UTC to begin with.  Unlike `Date`, an `OADate` isn't guaranteed to be fixed to UTC or any particular time zone.  If it was originally representing some local time, then you will need to compensate for that separately.

Comment: @MattJohnson, you seem to be true. But the code is shamelessly copied from decompiled mscorelib.dll source. Blame MS for that.

Answer (score 5):

This looks like it works... basically `ToBinary` just returns a representation where the bottom 58 bits are the ticks since the BCL epoch in UTC. This code just reverses that

```
private static final long UNIX_EPOCH = 62135596800000L;
public static Date fromDateTimeBinary(long value) {
    // Mask off the top bits, which hold the "kind" and
    // possibly offset.
    // This is irrelevant in Java, as a Date has no
    // notion of time zone
    value = value & 0x3fffffffffffffffL;
    // A tick in .NET is 100 nanoseconds. So a millisecond
    // is 10,000 ticks.
    value = value / 10000;
    return new Date(value - UNIX_EPOCH); 
}
```

I've tested that for a "local" `DateTime` and a "UTC" `DateTime`. It will treat an "unspecified" `DateTime` as being in UTC.

Overall it's not ideal, and you should talk to wherever you're getting the data from to *try* to change to a more portable format, but until then this should help. Do test it further though!

Comment: Did you see [how much more the framework does in `DateTime.FromBinary`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs#611)?

Comment: @MattJohnson: Fortunately only for the "local" case though :)

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.FromBinary()` deserializes a .NET-specific serialized version of `DateTime`. It works only with the binary data produced from a `DateTime.ToBinary()` call, not with any standard input data.

There is no Java equivalent, because the .NET `DateTime` class doesn't exist in Java.

If you are trying to save a .NET `DateTime` object to a binary format, and read it in to a Java application, you should be using a different format. For example, seconds since the UNIX epoch.

Comment: I can't handle the coming data

Answer (score 0):

C#'s binary serialization is .NET specific as it serializes the Ticks-property as Int64 and additionally the Kind-property whereas Javas DateTime is typically based on the unixtime (millis since 1970).

So i think you will not find a framework equivalent in Java. Have a look at this StackOverflow post for information how to get a Ticks equivalent in Java: [C# DateTime.Ticks equivalent in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706306/c-sharp-datetime-ticks-equivalent-in-java/)

I also would give [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) a quick shot. Maybe you will find a utility method there.

Answer (score 0):

You should choose an interchange format that makes more sense.

- If you can pass a string, use the [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.  In .Net, you would use `yourDateTime.ToString("o")`.
- If you want something more compact, pass a timestamp - such as a long integer of milliseconds since 1/1/1970 UTC.

Don't pass the output of `DateTime.ToBinary`.  You would have to implement a lot of things in Java that would not be worth it.  Specifically:

- The `Kind` property of the `DateTime` is embedded as part of the data. You'd have to filter it out and interpret it.  There isn't any direct equivalent in Java.
- You can see [in the .Net Framework Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs#611), that `FromBinary` has to deal with various time zone conversions - in case you serialize a `DateTime` with `Local` kind in one time zone and deserialize it in another.