# What is the equivalent of Datetime.FromBinary(long) in Java?

Tags: java, c#, datetime

C# has `Datetime.FromBinary(long)` method which accepts `long`. I have `long data = -8587633342590756227`.
`Datetime.FromBinary(-8587633342590756227)` which gives {7/30/2015 10:10:26 AM}. How to convert it to date-time format in Java?

Thanks

Comment: Can I suggest not storing/transmitting data in what is effectively a .NET-centric format to start with? Beyond that - look at the documentation for `DateTime.FromBinary`, which explains what the value is. Note that Java's `Date` doesn't have as much precision as `DateTime`, although `java.time.Instant` does (and more).

Comment: is it the one you are looking for ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23670516/what-is-the-equivalent-of-datetime-fromoadate-in-java-double-to-datetime-in-j

Comment: No, that's a different one I guess

Answer (score 0):

The value .Net (de-)serializes via `To-/FromBinary` seems very specific to .Net, so I don't think there's an easy way to convert that value into a `java.util.Date`.

The easiest way I can think of from the perspective of a Java developer would be to convert your .Net `DateTime` to Unix time (see [DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn823277(v=vs.110).aspx)) and then use that value for the `java.util.Date` [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date(long)) that accepts that value.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

x, = struct.unpack('q', File.read(8))

y=x+8587633342590756227

dt= datetime.datetime(2015,7,30,10,10,26,0) + datetime.timedelta(microseconds=y/10.)

Comment: Actually that is python. FYI.

Comment: And you gave a Python answer to a Java question for... what?