# DateTime does not show option for UtcNow

Tags: java, datetime

I am using the import : org.joda.time.DateTime

but while using dateTime, it does not contain DateTime.UtcNow?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following:

```
DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC);
```

From the javadoc:

> Obtains a DateTime set to the current system millisecond time using ISOChronology in the specified time zone.

Answer (score 1):

DateTime.UtcNow is c# (.Net) :)

For java, you can look at this answer :

[How can I get the current date and time in UTC or GMT in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308683/how-can-i-get-the-current-date-and-time-in-utc-or-gmt-in-java)

:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatGmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");
dateFormatGmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

//Local time zone   
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatLocal = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");

//Time in GMT
return dateFormatLocal.parse( dateFormatGmt.format(new Date()) );
```

Comment: Thanks....also can you tell me if "ticks" too is c#.

Comment: sure :) this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706306/c-sharp-datetime-ticks-equivalent-in-java

Comment: @ChiragNangru:- Yes [ticks is C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
DateTime utc = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
//If you want to get the time for a specific timezone then add it 
DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZone.forID("America/Los_Angeles");
DateTime dt = utc.toDateTime(tz);
```